# How do you make the screen update before displaying an alert?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I am making a chess website and want to display an alert to tell the players who has won. However, when the alert is displayed, the last move made is not shown until the alert is closed. The alert function is last in the code, so it should appear after source for the images of the squares have been changed. How do I make the screen update before displaying the alert? I didn't have or find any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: A naive solution would be putting the alert in a setTimeout. But you'd probably better creating your own modal, with your styles etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read through the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and include a minimal, complete, and reproducible example in your question.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is a `<dialog>` element available, please don't use `alert()`, not even for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The [`requestAnimationFrame()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) queues the callback to run *immediately before* rendering one frame. Once the browser starts working through the queue, all further calls to it count towards the frame *after*.

This means we can use it to essentially "wait" certain amounts of frames:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  // This callback runs immediately before frame A

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // This callback runs immediately before frame B; the frame after A
    
    // ...
  });
});
```

We can write a utility function for this:

```js
function waitFrames(n, callback) {
  if (n > 0) {
    // After next frame, wait n-1 frames
    requestAnimationFrame(() => waitFrames(n - 1, callback));
  } else {
    // Wait 0 frames; run before next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(callback);
  }
}
```

In your case, you'd want to **wait for 1 frame**.

Comment: No need to wait for yet another frame, just queue a task after rAF fired (e.g with `setTimeout( ,0)`).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to have an effect when I used it. I put the function in both `setTimeout(CheckGameOver(boardState),0)` and `waitFrames(CheckGameOver(boardState))` but neither of them fixed the issue, the alert still appeared before the screen updated. Same with when I tried `waitFrames(MovePiece)` (the function where the alert function is called), and `waitFrames(CheckGameOver)` (the function where the alert happens). Is there something I have done wrong when referencing the functions?

Comment: @Jloom5 It seems you have not specified the amount of frames to wait for. The first argument should be a number that specifies how many frames to wait for.

Comment: Isn't that what the variable n is for? I edited the code to set n inside the function for convenience.